# Why the default routing items cannot be removed when the ip on the interface is deleted?

Tags: linux, routing

On a linux machine, I have the following IP settings:

```
ruckus$ ifconfig -a

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:3E:90:07:8E:E0

      inet addr:172.18.140.3  Bcast:172.18.140.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::169:254:17:11/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1277606 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:619615 (605.0 KiB)

br0:169   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:3E:90:07:8E:E0 

      inet addr:169.254.17.11  Bcast:169.254.17.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

And the routing table is:

```
ruckus$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface

0.0.0.0         172.18.140.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.17.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

And then I delete the IP on interface br0

```
ruckus$ ifconfig br0 0.0.0.0

ruckus$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface

0.0.0.0         172.18.140.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.17.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

As you can see the default routing item is still existing. I think the kernel should remove the default routing items when the IP on the interface is delete. The most possible reason I think is that I am applying the "policy routing" on the linux machine. There is still a IP on the interface br0:169 so kernel does not delete the default routing item on br0?

Is that true and if so, why?

Comment: That's not the correct way  to delete an address. You should issue: *ip link set dev br0 down && ip addr flush dev br0*, pursuant to which you routing table will be empty.